# Page background doesn't display whole image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with a background image, choosen by random with javascript:

```
document.body.style.background= 'url('+randombgs[num]+')';
```

I have set the background to an imagefrom the `randombgs[]` array which contains 15 backgrounds. But the background gets cut off, and the whole image isn't displayed (see picture below)

This is what I see:
[image: This is what I see]

This is what I should see
[image: This is what I should see]

How can I fix this, so my browser shows the whole image and not 95% of it?

Comment: Fixed it by adding: document.body.style.backgroundSize =  "1980px 965px"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS background-size property:

```
body {
  background-size: contain;
}
```

The image will fit your container.

Comment: Don't do this with javascript. This rule will always be needed in your case, so just use CSS.  
Do you have any other content in your body at the moment?  
Could you provide a JSFiddle to show the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-size` property in CSS (with value `contain`).

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp for more details.

Not supported on IE8 and less: http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts only.